# System.Text.Json adds an extra curly bracket ONLY TO END so it causes exception

Tags: system.text.json

I am sending JSON object through TcpSocket. I deserialize it after destination receives. Usually first a few objects are sent and deserialized without issue! And then suddenly one comes with an extra curly braket only at the end then run time exception.

Seriosuly, what the hell is this ?

System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''}' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 32.'

```
{"Value":3,"Name":"Blood Sugar"}}


while(true)
{

     seperateSocketForEachRequest.Receive(byteMessage);
     seperateSocketForEachRequest.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FF"));
                
     string stringMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteMessage);

     stringMessage = stringMessage.Substring(0, stringMessage.IndexOf('\0'));

     Object message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object>(stringMessage);
 }
```

////////////////////////////////////////

```
while (Form.isGenerate)
 {
     Data newData = dataType.generate(person.generatingParameters);
     Thread.Sleep(500); 
     clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize<Data>(newData)));
    
     byte[] messageReceivedByte = new Byte[1024];
     clientSocket.Receive(messageReceivedByte);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code used to do this, as a [mcve]?

Comment: Are the sockets really necessary as part of the reproduction of the issue? Are you able to reproduce the issue without the sockets?

Comment: I didnt test it without sockets.

Comment: Why not? You're assuming that System.Text.Json is adding a curly brace, but it may be some issue with your code. You should remove everything you can until you've got the smallest possible bit of code that still exhibits the problematic behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It is caused of data transmission. Apparently same buffer is used for writing data received from socket and new data is written over old data. Therefore, when value of data is 2 digit number, no issue, when a data comes with 1 digit, boom.

```
{"Value":76,"Name":"Blood Sugar"} 
{"Value":99,"Name":"Blood Sugar"} 
{"Value":76,"Name":"Blood Sugar"} 
{"Value":1,"Name":"Blood Sugar"}}
```